# Constrained number template

Tags: c++, c++14

There are a lot of times where you need to ensure that a number stays within some constraints and I got annoyed of inventing a distinct class for every case so I decided to solve the problem once and for all. So I wrote a template which has semantics the same as a number except it checks the predicate each time its value is about to change.

Here are some design decisions:

- Compile time binding of predicate. I don't need runtime polymorphism.
- The violation of predicate should throw exception.
- The template will decay to underlying type as early as possible to allow intermediate values violate the predicate.
- It should be usable in any construct that accepts fundamental arithmetic types.
- On the other hand, it should work for arbitrary precision types as long as they have the same interface as fundamental types.
- It should be possible to derive from the template to add additional functions.

Declarations:

```
/// \file
/// \brief Header file that describes the CheckedNumber class template.
/// \author Lyberta
/// \copyright GNU GPLv3 or any later version.

#pragma once

#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

namespace ftz
{
namespace General
{

/// \brief A concept for a predicate.
template <typename T>
concept bool Predicate()
{
    return requires()
    {
        typename T::ValueType;
    } &&
    requires (typename T::ValueType value)
    {
        {T::Check(value)} -> void;
    };
}

/// \brief A checked number.
/// \details Checked number is a number which can't have some values which are
/// otherwise possible for the underlying type. For example, a floating point
/// number which can't be negative. This class takes a predicate class which
/// defines the underlying type of the value and a static function to check the
/// value. Predicate must throw std::domain_error if the value is illegal.
/// \tparam T Type of the predicate.

template <Predicate T>
class CheckedNumber
{
public:
    using ValueType = typename T::ValueType; ///< Underlying type of the value.

    /// \brief Constructor.
    /// \param[in] val Value to set.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If value is illegal.
    constexpr explicit CheckedNumber(ValueType val = ValueType{});

    /// \brief Returns the reference to the underlying value.
    /// \return Reference to the underlying value.
    constexpr const ValueType& GetValue() const noexcept;

    /// \brief Sets the underlying value.
    /// \param[in] newvalue Value to set.
    /// \return No return.
    constexpr void SetValue(ValueType newvalue);

    /// \brief Returns the underlying value.
    /// \return Underlying value.
    constexpr operator ValueType() const noexcept;

    /// \brief Sets the underlying value.
    /// \param[in] newvalue Value to set.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If value is illegal.
    constexpr CheckedNumber& operator=(ValueType newvalue);

    /// \brief Converts the underlying value to boolean.
    /// \return Result of the conversion.
    constexpr explicit operator bool() const;

    /// \brief Converts the underlying value to boolean and negates it.
    /// \return Negated result of the conversion.
    constexpr bool operator!() const;

    /// \brief Returns the underlying value.
    /// \return Underlying value.
    constexpr auto operator+() const;

    /// \brief Returns the underlying value with changed sign.
    /// \return Underlying value with changed sign.
    constexpr auto operator-() const;

    /// \brief Returns the binary negated underlying value.
    /// \return Binary negated underlying value.
    constexpr auto operator~() const;

    /// \brief Preincrements the underlying value.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error if result is illegal.
    CheckedNumber& operator++();

    /// \brief Postincrements the underlying value.
    /// \return Copy of this number before increment.
    /// \throw std::domain_error if result is illegal.
    CheckedNumber operator++(int);

    /// \brief Predecrements the underlying value.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error if result is illegal.
    CheckedNumber& operator--();

    /// \brief Postdecrements the underlying value.
    /// \return Copy of this number before decrement.
    /// \throw std::domain_error if result is illegal.
    CheckedNumber operator--(int);

    /// \brief Adds a value to the underlying value.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to add.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the sum is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    CheckedNumber& operator+=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Subtracts a value from the underlying value.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to subtract.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the difference is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    CheckedNumber& operator-=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Mulptiplies the underlying value by another value.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to multiply by.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the product is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    CheckedNumber& operator*=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Divides the underlying value by another value.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to divide by.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the quotient is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    CheckedNumber& operator/=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Computes the remainder of the division by another value.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to divide by.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the remainder is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    CheckedNumber& operator%=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Computes bitwise AND of underlying value and another value.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to compute with.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the result is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    CheckedNumber& operator&=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Computes bitwise OR of underlying value and another value.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to compute with.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the result is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    CheckedNumber& operator|=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Computes bitwise XOR of underlying value and another value.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to compute with.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the result is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    CheckedNumber& operator^=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Shifts the underlying value by several places to the left.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to shift by.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the result is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    CheckedNumber& operator<<=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Shifts the underlying value by several places to the right.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to shift by.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the result is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    CheckedNumber& operator>>=(const U& val);
private:
    ValueType value; ///< Underlying value.
};

/// \brief Adds two numbers together.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Sum of the numbers.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator+(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Adds two numbers together.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Sum of the numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator+(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Adds two numbers together.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Sum of the numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator+(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Subtracts one number from the other.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs Number to subtract from.
/// \param[in] rhs Number to subtracts.
/// \return Difference between the numbers.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator-(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Subtracts one number from the other.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs Number to subtract from.
/// \param[in] rhs Number to subtracts.
/// \return Difference between the numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator-(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Subtracts one number from the other.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs Number to subtract from.
/// \param[in] rhs Number to subtracts.
/// \return Difference between the numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator-(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Multiplies two numbers together.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Product of the numbers.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator*(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Multiplies two numbers together.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Product of the numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator*(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Multiplies two numbers together.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Product of the numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator*(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Divides one number by the other.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs Number to divide.
/// \param[in] rhs Number to divide by.
/// \return Quotient of the numbers.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator/(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Divides one number by the other.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs Number to divide.
/// \param[in] rhs Number to divide by.
/// \return Quotient of the numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator/(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Divides one number by the other.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs Number to divide.
/// \param[in] rhs Number to divide by.
/// \return Quotient of the numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator/(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the remainder of the division of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs Number to divide.
/// \param[in] rhs Number to divide by.
/// \return Remainder of the division.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator%(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the remainder of the division of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs Number to divide.
/// \param[in] rhs Number to divide by.
/// \return Remainder of the division.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator%(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the remainder of the division of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs Number to divide.
/// \param[in] rhs Number to divide by.
/// \return Remainder of the division.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator%(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the bitwise AND of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Bitwise AND of two numbers.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator&(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the bitwise AND of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Bitwise AND of two numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator&(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the bitwise AND of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Bitwise AND of two numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator&(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the bitwise OR of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Bitwise OR of two numbers.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator|(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the bitwise OR of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Bitwise OR of two numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator|(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the bitwise OR of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Bitwise OR of two numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator|(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the bitwise XOR of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Bitwise OR of two numbers.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator^(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the bitwise XOR of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Bitwise OR of two numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator^(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the bitwise XOR of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Bitwise OR of two numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator^(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the shift of the number by several places to the left.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs Number to shift.
/// \param[in] rhs Number to shift by.
/// \return Result of the shift.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator<<(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the shift of the number by several places to the left.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs Number to shift.
/// \param[in] rhs Number to shift by.
/// \return Result of the shift.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator<<(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the shift of the number by several places to the left.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs Number to shift.
/// \param[in] rhs Number to shift by.
/// \return Result of the shift.
template <Predicate T, typename U,
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<std::ios_base, U>::value>>
//std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<std::ios_base, U>>> C++17
auto operator<<(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the shift of the number by several places to the right.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs Number to shift.
/// \param[in] rhs Number to shift by.
/// \return Result of the shift.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator>>(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the shift of the number by several places to the right.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs Number to shift.
/// \param[in] rhs Number to shift by.
/// \return Result of the shift.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator>>(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the shift of the number by several places to the right.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs Number to shift.
/// \param[in] rhs Number to shift by.
/// \return Result of the shift.
template <Predicate T, typename U,
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<std::ios_base, U>::value>>
//std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<std::ios_base, U>>> C++17
auto operator>>(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the logical AND of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Logical AND of two numbers.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator&&(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the logical AND of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Logical AND of two numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator&&(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the logical AND of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Logical AND of two numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator&&(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the logical OR of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Logical OR of two numbers.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator||(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the logical OR of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Logical OR of two numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator||(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Returns the logical OR of two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return Logical OR of two numbers.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator||(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if numbers are equal, false otherwise.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
bool operator==(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if numbers are equal, false otherwise.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator==(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if numbers are equal, false otherwise.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator==(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if numbers are not equal, false otherwise.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
bool operator!=(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if numbers are not equal, false otherwise.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator!=(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if numbers are not equal, false otherwise.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator!=(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if first number is less than second, false otherwise.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
bool operator<(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if first number is less than second, false otherwise.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator<(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if first number is less than second, false otherwise.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator<(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if first number is greater than second, false otherwise.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
bool operator>(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if first number is greater than second, false otherwise.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator>(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if first number is greater than second, false otherwise.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator>(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if first number is less than or equal to second, false
/// otherwise.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
bool operator<=(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if first number is less than or equal to second, false
/// otherwise.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator<=(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if first number is less than or equal to second, false
/// otherwise.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator<=(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if first number is greater than or equal to second, false
/// otherwise.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
bool operator>=(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if first number is greater than or equal to second, false
/// otherwise.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator>=(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs);

/// \brief Compares two numbers.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] lhs First number.
/// \param[in] rhs Second number.
/// \return True if first number is greater than or equal to second, false
/// otherwise.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator>=(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs);

/// \brief Reads a number from stream.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam CharT Character type of the stream.
/// \tparam Traits Traits type of the stream.
/// \param[in,out] stream Stream to read from.
/// \param[out] number Number to write to.
/// \return Reference to stream.
/// \throw std::domain_error If the value read is illegal.
template <Predicate T, typename CharT, typename Traits>
std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& operator>>(
    std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& stream, CheckedNumber<T>& number);

/// \brief Writes a number to stream.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \tparam CharT Character type of the stream.
/// \tparam Traits Traits type of the stream.
/// \param[in,out] stream Stream to write to.
/// \param[in] number Number to read from.
/// \return Reference to stream.
template <Predicate T, typename CharT, typename Traits>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& stream, const CheckedNumber<T>& number);

/// \brief Returns the absolute value of the underlying value.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \param[in] number Input value.
/// \return Absolute value of the underlying value.
template <Predicate T>
auto abs(const CheckedNumber<T>& number);

/// \brief Returns the e raised to the power of the underlying value.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \param[in] number Input value.
/// \return E raised to the power of the underlying value.
template <Predicate T>
auto exp(const CheckedNumber<T>& number);

/// \brief Returns the natural logarithm of the underlying value.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \param[in] number Input value.
/// \return Natural logarithm of the underlying value.
template <Predicate T>
auto log(const CheckedNumber<T>& number);

/// \brief Returns the base-10 logarithm of the underlying value.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \param[in] number Input value.
/// \return Base-10 logarithm of the underlying value.
template <Predicate T>
auto log10(const CheckedNumber<T>& number);

/// \brief Returns the base raised to the power of the exponent.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] base Base value.
/// \param[in] exponent Exponent value.
/// \return Base raised to the power of the exponent.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto pow(const CheckedNumber<T>& base, const CheckedNumber<U>& exponent);

/// \brief Returns the base raised to the power of the exponent.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] base Base value.
/// \param[in] exponent Exponent value.
/// \return Base raised to the power of the exponent.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto pow(const CheckedNumber<T>& base, const U& exponent);

/// \brief Returns the base raised to the power of the exponent.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] base Base value.
/// \param[in] exponent Exponent value.
/// \return Base raised to the power of the exponent.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto pow(const U& base, const CheckedNumber<T>& exponent);

/// \brief Returns the square root of the underlying value.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \param[in] number Input value.
/// \return Square root of the underlying value.
template <Predicate T>
auto sqrt(const CheckedNumber<T>& number);

/// \brief Returns the sine of the underlying value.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \param[in] number Input value.
/// \return Sine of the underlying value.
template <Predicate T>
auto sin(const CheckedNumber<T>& number);

/// \brief Returns the cosine of the underlying value.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \param[in] number Input value.
/// \return Cosine of the underlying value.
template <Predicate T>
auto cos(const CheckedNumber<T>& number);

/// \brief Returns the tangent of the underlying value.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \param[in] number Input value.
/// \return Tangent of the underlying value.
template <Predicate T>
auto tan(const CheckedNumber<T>& number);

/// \brief Returns the Arc sine of the underlying value.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \param[in] number Input value.
/// \return Arc sine of the underlying value.
template <Predicate T>
auto asin(const CheckedNumber<T>& number);

/// \brief Returns the arc cosine of the underlying value.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \param[in] number Input value.
/// \return Arc cosine of the underlying value.
template <Predicate T>
auto acos(const CheckedNumber<T>& number);

/// \brief Returns the arc tangent of the underlying value.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \param[in] number Input value.
/// \return Arc tangent of the underlying value.
template <Predicate T>
auto atan(const CheckedNumber<T>& number);

/// \brief Returns the arc tangent of y / x.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Predicate of the second checked number.
/// \param[in] y Y value.
/// \param[in] x X value.
/// \return Arc tangent of y / x.
template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto atan2(const CheckedNumber<T>& y, const CheckedNumber<U>& x);

/// \brief Returns the arc tangent of y / x.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] y Y value.
/// \param[in] x X value.
/// \return Arc tangent of y / x.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto atan2(const CheckedNumber<T>& y, const U& x);

/// \brief Returns the arc tangent of y / x.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the first checked number.
/// \tparam U Type of another number.
/// \param[in] y Y value.
/// \param[in] x X value.
/// \return Arc tangent of y / x.
template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto atan2(const U& y, const CheckedNumber<T>& x);

/// \brief Returns the hyperbolic sine of the underlying value.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \param[in] number Input value.
/// \return Hyperbolic sine of the underlying value.
template <Predicate T>
auto sinh(const CheckedNumber<T>& number);

/// \brief Returns the hyperbolic cosine of the underlying value.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \param[in] number Input value.
/// \return Hyperbolic cosine of the underlying value.
template <Predicate T>
auto cosh(const CheckedNumber<T>& number);

/// \brief Returns the hyperbolic tangent of the underlying value.
/// \tparam T Predicate of the checked number.
/// \param[in] number Input value.
/// \return Hyperbolic tangent of the underlying value.
template <Predicate T>
auto tanh(const CheckedNumber<T>& number);

}
}

#include "CheckedNumber.hpp"
```

Definitions:

```
/// \file
/// \brief Internal header file that contains implementation of the
/// CheckedNumber class template.
/// \author Lyberta
/// \copyright GNU GPLv3 or any later version.

#pragma once

#include <cmath>

namespace ftz
{
namespace General
{

template <typename T>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>::CheckedNumber(ValueType val)
    : value{std::move(val)}
{
    T::Check(value);
}

template <typename T>
constexpr const typename CheckedNumber<T>::ValueType& CheckedNumber<T>::
    GetValue() const noexcept
{
    return value;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr void CheckedNumber<T>::SetValue(ValueType newvalue)
{
    T::Check(newvalue);
    value = std::move(newvalue);
}

template <typename T>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>::operator ValueType() const noexcept
{
    return value;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator=(ValueType newvalue)
{
    T::Check(newvalue);
    value = std::move(newvalue);
}

template <typename T>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>::operator bool() const
{
    return value;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr bool CheckedNumber<T>::operator!() const
{
    return !value;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr auto CheckedNumber<T>::operator+() const
{
    return +value;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr auto CheckedNumber<T>::operator-() const
{
    return -value;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr auto CheckedNumber<T>::operator~() const
{
    return ~value;
}

template <typename T>
CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator++()
{
    ValueType result = value;
    ++result;
    T::Check(result);
    value = std::move(result);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
CheckedNumber<T> CheckedNumber<T>::operator++(int)
{
    CheckedNumber<T> savedvalue{value};
    ValueType result = value;
    result++;
    T::Check(result);
    value = std::move(result);
    return savedvalue;
}

template <typename T>
CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator--()
{
    ValueType result = value;
    --result;
    T::Check(result);
    value = std::move(result);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
CheckedNumber<T> CheckedNumber<T>::operator--(int)
{
    CheckedNumber<T> savedvalue{value};
    ValueType result = value;
    result--;
    T::Check(result);
    value = std::move(result);
    return savedvalue;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator+=(const U& val)
{
    ValueType result = value + val;
    T::Check(result);
    value = std::move(result);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator-=(const U& val)
{
    ValueType result = value - val;
    T::Check(result);
    value = std::move(result);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator*=(const U& val)
{
    ValueType result = value * val;
    T::Check(result);
    value = std::move(result);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator/=(const U& val)
{
    ValueType result = value / val;
    T::Check(result);
    value = std::move(result);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator%=(const U& val)
{
    ValueType result = value % val;
    T::Check(result);
    value = std::move(result);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator&=(const U& val)
{
    ValueType result = value & val;
    T::Check(result);
    value = std::move(result);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator|=(const U& val)
{
    ValueType result = value | val;
    T::Check(result);
    value = std::move(result);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator^=(const U& val)
{
    ValueType result = value | val;
    T::Check(result);
    value = std::move(result);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator<<=(const U& val)
{
    ValueType result = value << val;
    T::Check(result);
    value = std::move(result);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator>>=(const U& val)
{
    ValueType result = value >> val;
    T::Check(result);
    value = std::move(result);
    return *this;
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator+(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() + rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator+(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() + rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator+(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs + rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator-(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() - rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator-(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() - rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator-(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs - rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator*(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() * rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator*(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() * rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator*(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs * rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator/(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() + rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator/(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() / rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator/(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs / rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator%(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() + rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator%(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() + rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator%(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs + rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator&(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() & rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator&(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() & rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator&(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs & rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator|(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() | rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator|(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() | rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator|(const U& lhs,
    const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs | rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator^(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() ^ rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator^(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() ^ rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator^(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs ^ rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator<<(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() << rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator<<(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() << rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U,
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<std::ios_base, U>::value>>
//std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<std::ios_base, U>>> C++17
auto operator<<(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs << rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator>>(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() >> rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator>>(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() >> rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U,
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<std::ios_base, U>::value>>
//std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<std::ios_base, U>>> C++17
auto operator>>(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs >> rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator&&(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() && rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator&&(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() && rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator&&(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs && rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto operator||(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() || rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator||(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() || rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto operator||(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs || rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
bool operator==(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() == rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator==(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() == rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator==(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs == rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
bool operator!=(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() != rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator!=(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() != rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator!=(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs != rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
bool operator<(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() < rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator<(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() < rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator<(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs < rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
bool operator>(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() > rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator>(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() > rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator>(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs > rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
bool operator<=(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() <= rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator<=(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() <= rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator<=(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs <= rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
bool operator>=(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const CheckedNumber<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() >= rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator>=(const CheckedNumber<T>& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetValue() >= rhs;
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
bool operator>=(const U& lhs, const CheckedNumber<T>& rhs)
{
    return lhs >= rhs.GetValue();
}

template <Predicate T, typename CharT, typename Traits>
std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& operator>>(
    std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& stream, CheckedNumber<T>& number)
{
    typename CheckedNumber<T>::ValueType value;
    stream >> value;
    number = value;
    return stream;
}

template <Predicate T, typename CharT, typename Traits>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& stream, const CheckedNumber<T>& number)
{
    stream << number.GetValue();
    return stream;
}

template <Predicate T>
auto abs(const CheckedNumber<T>& number)
{
    using std::abs;
    return abs(number.GetValue());
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto exp(const CheckedNumber<T>& number, const U& exponent)
{
    using std::exp;
    return exp(number.GetValue(),
        exponent);
}

template <Predicate T>
auto log(const CheckedNumber<T>& number)
{
    using std::log;
    return log(number.GetValue());
}

template <Predicate T>
auto log10(const CheckedNumber<T>& number)
{
    using std::log10;
    return log10(number.GetValue());
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto pow(const CheckedNumber<T>& base, const CheckedNumber<U>& exponent)
{
    using std::pow;
    return pow(base.GetValue(), exponent.GetValue());
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto pow(const CheckedNumber<T>& base, const U& exponent)
{
    using std::pow;
    return pow(base.GetValue(), exponent);
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto pow(const U& base, const CheckedNumber<T>& exponent)
{
    using std::pow;
    return pow(base, exponent.GetValue());
}

template <Predicate T>
auto sqrt(const CheckedNumber<T>& number)
{
    using std::sqrt;
    return sqrt(number.GetValue());
}

template <Predicate T>
auto sin(const CheckedNumber<T>& number)
{
    using std::sin;
    return sin(number.GetValue());
}

template <Predicate T>
auto cos(const CheckedNumber<T>& number)
{
    using std::cos;
    return cos(number.GetValue());
}

template <Predicate T>
auto tan(const CheckedNumber<T>& number)
{
    using std::tan;
    return tan(number.GetValue());
}

template <Predicate T>
auto asin(const CheckedNumber<T>& number)
{
    using std::asin;
    return asin(number.GetValue());
}

template <Predicate T>
auto acos(const CheckedNumber<T>& number)
{
    using std::acos;
    return acos(number.GetValue());
}

template <Predicate T>
auto atan(const CheckedNumber<T>& number)
{
    using std::atan;
    return atan(number.GetValue());
}

template <Predicate T, Predicate U>
auto atan2(const CheckedNumber<T>& y, const CheckedNumber<U>& x)
{
    using std::atan2;
    return atan2(y.GetValue(), x.GetValue());
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto atan2(const CheckedNumber<T>& y, const U& x)
{
    using std::atan2;
    return atan2(y.GetValue(), x);
}

template <Predicate T, typename U>
auto atan2(const U& y, const CheckedNumber<T>& x)
{
    using std::atan2;
    return atan2(y, x.GetValue());
}

template <Predicate T>
auto sinh(const CheckedNumber<T>& number)
{
    using std::sinh;
    return abs(number.GetValue());
}

template <Predicate T>
auto cosh(const CheckedNumber<T>& number)
{
    using std::cosh;
    return cosh(number.GetValue());
}

template <Predicate T>
auto atanh(const CheckedNumber<T>& number)
{
    using std::atanh;
    return atanh(number.GetValue());
}

}
}
```

Now first, I've started marking functions `constexpr` but quickly found that I don't have much knowledge of `constexpr` so I don't know which functions should be constexpr. Which ones? It looks like I can mark all functions `constexpr`.

Second, I haven't added non-operator functions such as `abs` or `sin`. I'd want to overload `std` versions (this is how `std::complex` and `std::valarray` do this) but it looks like it is undefined behavior. So I don't know what to do. Suggestions?

EDIT: OK, since I can't overload `std` functions, I've put them in the same namespace as template so I'd need to use unqualified, say, `abs`, and rely on ADL. So far, I've added all functions that are declared for `std::valarray` but it looks like C++11 and 14 added more stuff to `<cmath>` so I'll add them too.

EDIT2: I've just found that if I derive from this template, I need to import all overloaded operators into the derived class. Is there a better way?

Comment: Ok, maybe I read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513417/what-can-and-cant-i-specialize-in-the-std-namespace totally wrong...

Comment: On the other hand, I can't partially specialize function templates so that means I can't specialize, say , `std::sin` for `CheckedNumber<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Headers

For forward declarations of streams, use `<iosfwd>` in the header - it's more lightweight than requiring `<istream>` and `<ostream>`.  You'll need the latter two for the implementation, of course.

We're missing `<type_traits>`, which is required for `std::enable_if_t` and `std::is_base_of`.  (Aside: why not use `std::is_base_of_v` instead?).  We also need `<utility>`, for `std::move`.

### Terminology

I expect a "predicate" to *return* a boolean value.  A function that *throws* should be called an "assertion".

It might also be better if we used the standard `operator()` for the test, and allow passing a lambda (or indeed, any `std::function`) as the predicate.  Unfortunately, C++14 doesn't allow using a callable as a template parameter, so that would require us to carry a member around with each value.

### Don't overload the short-circuiting operators

Overloading `operator&&` and `operator||` can cause surprises for users, as the second argument is always evaluated, unlike with the built-in versions.  Instead, allow the arguments to convert to `bool` in the usual way (remember that an [`explicit operator bool` will be used in this context](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39995573) if necessary).

### `GetValue` and `SetValue` seem pointless

These two functions add no value (!) to the class, since they just duplicate `operator ValueType()` and `operator=`.

### Assignment operators should return `*this`

```
template <typename T>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator=(ValueType newvalue)
{
    T::Check(newvalue);
    value = std::move(newvalue);
    // oops!
}
```

### Implement copying

In case the predicate is expensive, allow copy construction and assignment.  These methods can be `noexcept`.

### Don't implement non-assigning operators

There's no need for operators such as (unary or binary) `+` and `-`, or `~`, `|`, etc - we're happy with the standard fallback using the conversion to `ValueType`.  The same goes for the `<cmath>` functions - they will work just fine with the implicit conversion to the underlying type.

### Assigning operators can be `noexcept`...

... if the underlying type's operator is `noexcept`.  Let's assume that it is, since this is intended for arithmetic types.

### Use the assignment operator instead of repeating test code

Consider the implementation of `operator+`:

```
{
    ValueType result = value + val;
    T::Check(result);
    value = std::move(result);
    return *this;
}
```

Most of that merely duplicates assigning from `value + val`, so re-use that:

```
{
    return *this = value + val;
}
```

### Write some tests

Without tests, it's not obvious that you've used `|` instead of `^` in the implementation of `operator^=()`, for example.

---

## Modified code

I was able to reduce much of the code, without losing any of the functionality:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <istream>

namespace ftz
{
namespace General
{

template <typename T>
concept bool Predicate()
{
    return requires()
    {
        typename T::ValueType;
    } &&
    requires (typename T::ValueType value)
    {
        {T::Check(value)} -> void;
    };
}

/// \brief A checked number.
/// \details Checked number is a number which can't have some values which are
/// otherwise possible for the underlying type. For example, a floating point
/// number which can't be negative. This class takes a predicate class which
/// defines the underlying type of the value and a static function to check the
/// value. Predicate must throw std::domain_error if the value is illegal.
/// \tparam T Type of the predicate.
template<Predicate T>
class CheckedNumber
{
public:
    using ValueType = typename T::ValueType; ///< Underlying type of the value.

    /// \brief Constructor.
    /// \param[in] val Value to set.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If value is illegal.
    constexpr CheckedNumber(ValueType val = ValueType{});

    /// \brief Returns the underlying value.
    /// \return Underlying value.
    constexpr operator ValueType() const noexcept { return value; }

    /// \brief Preincrements the underlying value.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error if result is illegal.
    constexpr CheckedNumber& operator++();

    /// \brief Postincrements the underlying value.
    /// \return Copy of this number before increment.
    /// \throw std::domain_error if the incremented value is illegal.
    constexpr CheckedNumber operator++(int);

    /// \brief Predecrements the underlying value.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error if result is illegal.
    constexpr CheckedNumber& operator--();

    /// \brief Postdecrements the underlying value.
    /// \return Copy of this number before decrement.
    /// \throw std::domain_error if the decremented value is illegal.
    constexpr CheckedNumber operator--(int);

    /// \brief Adds a value to the underlying value.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to add.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the sum is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    constexpr CheckedNumber& operator+=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Subtracts a value from the underlying value.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to subtract.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the difference is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    constexpr CheckedNumber& operator-=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Mulptiplies the underlying value by another value.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to multiply by.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the product is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    constexpr CheckedNumber& operator*=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Divides the underlying value by another value.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to divide by.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the quotient is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    constexpr CheckedNumber& operator/=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Computes the remainder of the division by another value.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to divide by.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the remainder is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    constexpr CheckedNumber& operator%=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Computes bitwise AND of underlying value and another value.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to compute with.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the result is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    constexpr CheckedNumber& operator&=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Computes bitwise OR of underlying value and another value.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to compute with.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the result is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    constexpr CheckedNumber& operator|=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Computes bitwise XOR of underlying value and another value.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to compute with.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the result is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    constexpr CheckedNumber& operator^=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Shifts the underlying value by several places to the left.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to shift by.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the result is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    constexpr CheckedNumber& operator<<=(const U& val);

    /// \brief Shifts the underlying value by several places to the right.
    /// \tparam U Type of the value.
    /// \param[in] val Value to shift by.
    /// \return Reference to this number.
    /// \throw std::domain_error If the result is illegal.
    template <typename U>
    constexpr CheckedNumber& operator>>=(const U& val);

private:
    ValueType value; ///< Underlying value.
};

// Implementations

template <typename T>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>::CheckedNumber(ValueType val)
    : value{std::move(val)}
{
    T::Check(value);
}

template <typename T>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator++()
{
    auto result = value;
    return *this = ++result;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T> CheckedNumber<T>::operator++(int)
{
    auto const savedvalue = *this;
    auto result = value;
    result++;
    *this = result;
    return savedvalue;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator--()
{
    auto result = value;
    return *this = --result;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T> CheckedNumber<T>::operator--(int)
{
    auto const savedvalue = *this;
    auto result = value;
    result--;
    *this = result;
    return savedvalue;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator+=(const U& val)
{
    return *this = value + val;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator-=(const U& val)
{
    return *this = value - val;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator*=(const U& val)
{
    return *this = value * val;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator/=(const U& val)
{
    return *this = value / val;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator%=(const U& val)
{
    return *this = value % val;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator&=(const U& val)
{
    return *this = value & val;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator|=(const U& val)
{
    return *this = value | val;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator^=(const U& val)
{
    return *this = value ^ val;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator<<=(const U& val)
{
    return *this = value << val;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
constexpr CheckedNumber<T>& CheckedNumber<T>::operator>>=(const U& val)
{
    return *this = value >> val;
}


template <Predicate T, typename CharT, typename Traits>
std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& in,
                                              CheckedNumber<T>& number)
{
    typename CheckedNumber<T>::ValueType value;
    if (in >> value) number = value;
    return in;
}



}
}
```

Here's a start on the tests (using Google Test, but you should be able to adapt to your favourite test runner):

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

struct assert_even
{
    using ValueType = int;
    static constexpr void Check(ValueType n) {
        if (n % 2)
            throw std::domain_error("Violated EvenNumber constraint");
    }
};

struct assert_small
{
    using ValueType = char;
    static constexpr void Check(ValueType n) {
        if (n < -9 or 9 < n)
            throw std::domain_error("Violated SmallNumber constraint");
    }
};

struct assert_small_double
{
    using ValueType = double;
    static constexpr void Check(ValueType n) {
        if (n < -9 or 9 < n)
            throw std::domain_error("Violated SmallNumber constraint");
    }
};


using ftz::General::CheckedNumber;

using EvenNumber = CheckedNumber<assert_even>;
using SmallNumber = CheckedNumber<assert_small>;
using SmallDouble = CheckedNumber<assert_small_double>;


TEST(EvenNumber, construct)
{
    EXPECT_NO_THROW({EvenNumber a{0};});
    EXPECT_THROW({EvenNumber a{1};}, std::domain_error);
}

TEST(EvenNumber, istream)
{
    EvenNumber a{6};
    std::istringstream in{"3 2"};
    EXPECT_THROW(in >> a, std::domain_error);
    EXPECT_EQ(a, 6);            // unchanged
    EXPECT_TRUE(in >> a);
    EXPECT_EQ(a, 2);
    EXPECT_FALSE(in >> a);      // end of stream
    EXPECT_EQ(a, 2);            // unchanged
}

TEST(EvenNumber, increment)
{
    EvenNumber a;
    EXPECT_THROW({++a;}, std::domain_error);
    EXPECT_THROW({a++;}, std::domain_error);
    EXPECT_EQ(a, 0);            // strong exception guarantee
}
TEST(EvenNumber, add)
{
    EvenNumber a;
    EXPECT_THROW({a+=1;}, std::domain_error);
    EXPECT_EQ(a+=2, 2);
}
TEST(EvenNumber, false)
{
    EvenNumber a;
    EXPECT_FALSE(a);
}
TEST(EvenNumber, true)
{
    EvenNumber a = 6;
    EXPECT_TRUE(a);
}
TEST(EvenNumber, unary_negate)
{
    EvenNumber a = 6;
    EXPECT_EQ(-a, -6);
}

TEST(SmallNumber, construct)
{
    EXPECT_THROW({SmallNumber a{-10};}, std::domain_error);
    EXPECT_NO_THROW({SmallNumber a{-9};});
    EXPECT_NO_THROW({SmallNumber a{};});
    EXPECT_NO_THROW({SmallNumber a{9};});
    EXPECT_THROW({SmallNumber a{10};}, std::domain_error);
}

TEST(SmallNumber, increment)
{
    SmallNumber a{8};
    EXPECT_EQ(++a, 9);
    EXPECT_THROW({a++;}, std::domain_error);
    EXPECT_EQ(a, 9);            // strong exception guarantee
}

TEST(SmallNumber, multiply)
{
    SmallNumber a{4};
    EXPECT_EQ(a*4, 16);
    EXPECT_THROW({a*=4;}, std::domain_error);
    EXPECT_EQ(a, 4);            // strong exception guarantee
}


TEST(SmallDouble, trigonometric)
{
    SmallDouble a{0};
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(std::sin(a), 0);
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(std::cos(a), 1);
}
```

Comment: How are you using concept and constrained template parameters in c++14 ?

Comment: `g++-8 -std=c++14 -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds  -Weffc++    -fconcepts -pthread`

Comment: Copy ctor is generated automatically so there is no need to `default` it. And `>>` with `basic_istream` is still required to be manually implemented. Otherwise, everything is good.

Comment: Thanks @Lyberta - now fixed.  The copy constructor and assignment operator really shouldn't be there, as that inhibits compiler-generated move construct/assign.  I've added a stream-in operator and a simple test for it.